# Stuck After run command NPM RUN DEV (Laravel)

Tags: vite, laravel-9

PS C:\revi\project laravel\laravel9frame> npm run dev
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> dev
> vite

vite v2.9.14 dev server running at:

> Local: http://localhost:3000/
> Network: use `--host` to expose

ready in 479ms.

Laravel v9.20.0

> APP_URL: http://localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `npm run dev` I think you want `npm run build`

Answer (score 0):

use command:

```
npm run build
```

instead

```
npm run dev
```